# Decode file name from path (Swift 5)

Tags: swift, file, swift5

```
let FileName = ("\(urls[0])" as NSString).lastPathComponent
```

**full file url:** file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2BA0F976-0A79-43E8-B5E6-28A8F0AE4D63/tmp/vladKarlugin.Documents-Inbox/Car%20Configurator.pdf

Im get file name from path **"Car%20Configurator.pdf"**, but true name is **"Car Configuration"**

How can I'm decode name?

Comment: What kind of URL does `urls` contain?

Comment: @vadian File path

Comment: "percent escaping" is what's you are missing and what should be in your next search ;) Else `let name = ((path as NSString).lastPathComponent as NSString).deletingPathExtension.removingPercentEncoding`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an URL, delete the path extension and get the last path component.

```
let fileName = URL(string: urls[0])!.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
```